# Python WSGI server + controller in a single event loop

Tags: python, wsgi

I need to implement a server that, within a single event loop, would run and server a WSGI application (a web service written in werkzeug in particular) and, at the same time, once in a while call a specific function, which could control the server (e.g. it could pause it or shut it down). (The body of the function is not important, it might for example just check the current time or the state of another process.)

I can imagine doing this in two separate processes and having a dedicated web service interface. The solution described above seems to me better though.

Do you have any ideas how to approach this task?

Thank you,
Jakub

Comment: what about two threads?

Comment: I'm not sure if threads would help too much. The question is (and maybe the fundamental question in fact) _how to communicate with the event loop that is running a wsgi app_, i.e. after starting the main loop (e.g. after run_simple from werkzeug, reactor.run from Twisted or serve_forever from gevent etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have figured out how to do this with Twisted. Something like

```
from twisted.web import server, resource
from twisted.internet import reactor, endpoints
from twisted.internet.task import LoopingCall
from twisted.web.wsgi import WSGIResource

lc = LoopingCall(server_controller)
# run server_controller once a second
lc.start(1.0)
# serve a WSGI application
resource = WSGIResource(reactor, reactor.getThreadPool(), application)
site = server.Site(resource)
reactor.listenTCP(8080, site)
# enter into the even loop
reactor.run()
```